# Android: Checking internet connectivity hangs the UI

Tags: java, android

in my app, I display an `ErrorFragment` object with a RETRY button to re-check for internet if there is none. However, when the user has established internet connectivity, and clicked the RETRY button, the UI hangs for a couple seconds.

I know not to perform this task on the main thread, so I implemented the following:

```
public class MainFragment extends VerticalGridFragment
{
    ....

    if (isConnectedToInternet() == true)
    {
        // Load data
    }
    else
    {
        displayInternetError();
    }

    public void displayInternetError()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "displayInternetError");

        final ErrorFragment error = new ErrorFragment();

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_browse_fragment, error)
                .commit();

        error.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lb_ic_sad_cloud, null));
        error.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.no_internet_message));
        error.setDefaultBackground(true);

        error.setButtonText(getResources().getString(R.string.retry_connection));

        error.setButtonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                if (isConnectedToInternet() == true)
                {
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(error).commit();
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

                    Singleton.getInstance().setInternetErrorShown(false);
                    prepareBackgroundManager();
                    setupFragment();
                    setupEventListeners();
                }
                else
                {
                    Singleton.getInstance().setInternetErrorShown(true);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ...

     private class GetInternetStatus extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean>
    {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            return hasInternetAccess();
        }

        protected boolean hasInternetAccess()
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

                HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android Application:1");
                urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 30);
                urlc.connect();

                // http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html
                if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200 || urlc.getResponseCode() > 400)
                {
                    // Requested site is available
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Error while trying to connect
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Checking for all possible internet connections
    public  boolean isConnectedToInternet()
    {
        Boolean result = false;

        try
        {
            // Get the result after executing AsyncTask
            result = new GetInternetStatus().execute().get();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    ....
}
```

But it still hangs and the UI is unresponsive. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: While, yes, Google, is quick to respond, you may want to "ping" a server other than google for a quicker load-time.

Answer (score 1):

It hangs the UI because even though you are using an `AsyncTask`, you are starting it and then immediately trying to get the result of it..  Instead, use the `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method to either load the data or call `displayInternetError`.

Comment: Are you saying to invoke `hasInternetAccess` on `onPostExecute` instead of `doInBackground`?

Comment: @Pangu No, I'm saying to make isConnectedToInternet a void method that just kicks off the AsyncTask. And then the AsyncTask will call the appropriate method itself from within onPostExecute.

Comment: Of course, at that point it might be clearer to rename some of the methods: isConnectedToInternet -> checkIsConnectedToInternet, etc..

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand this conceptually. I make `isConnectedToInternet` a void, ok got it, then I kick off `AsyncTask` within `isConnectedToInternet`. Then within `GetInternetStatus `, I call `hasInternetAccess` within `onPostExecute` instead of `doInBackground`?

Comment: You kick off the `AsyncTask` which does the slow internet check (as you have it now), but then from `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute` method you handle the result of the check and either load the data or call `displayInternetError`.  Read the `AsyncTask` docs for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html